# How to find item index just added into my data binding ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, observablecollection

I have `ListView` binding with my collection:

```
private ObservableCollection<MyData> files{ get; set; }

<ListView Name="listview" ItemsSource="{Binding files}" >

public MyData
{
   public string FileName { get; set; }
   public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
   public int index { get; set; }
}
```

Add items into my collection:

```
MyData myData...
files.Add(myData);
listview.ItemsSource = files;
```

Now i want to add the option to remove selected file\files from my list so i added right click menu:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Name="removeFileMenuItem" Header="Remove file"
             Click="removeFileMenuItem_Click">
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

So when add file into my collection i want to get the item index and when i want to remove this item i will use it this way:

```
private void removeFileMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      if (listview.SelectedIndex == -1)
          return;
      MyData myData = listview.SelectedItem as MyData;
      if (myData != null)
      {
         file.RemoveAt(myData.index);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of work with `SelectedIndex`, You could work with `SelectedItem`,  so you take directly the your selected `data model`, to remove it subsequently, his method would look like this:

```
private void removeFileMenuItem_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var myData = listview.SelectedItem as MyData;
    if (myData != null)
        files.Remove (myData);
}
```

If You use in this way, you no need of `property` `index`, you could implement the `Equals` method to inform the model of equality rules, in this case I'll consider which your rule is the `FileName` `property`. Your data model would look like this:

```
public MyData
{
   public string FileName { get; set; }
   public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }

   public override bool Equals(object obj)
   {
       if (!(obj is MyData)) return false;
       return this.FileName.Equals(
              ((MyData)obj).FileName);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `Remove` method of the `ObservableCollection` class. It finds the object you pass in and removes it from the collection.

```
    private void removeFileMenuItem_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listview.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return;
        MyData myData = listview.SelectedItem as MyData;
        if (myData != null)
        {
            file.Remove (myData);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.